# update values dynamically ?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have to write a program that will take formulas from the user and calculate them.

```
    Age, Height, fights, (age+height)*fights <- user defined
    10, 5, 10, 150 <- I calculate this 
    1, 2, 1, 3 <- I calculate this
```

But now let say I change the values around and I want the formula column to update dynamically is there anyway to go about doing that ? I am storing by each row into an array list which is array list of array list. Any advice or guidance would be really helpful thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can revise this to make a simple engine

```
public interface Function<T> {
    T operate(Map<String,T> values);
}

public class Calculation<T> {

     private Map<String,T> values;

     private Function<T> function;

     public Calculation(Map<String,T> values, Function<T> function) {
         this.values = new HashMap<String,T>(values);
         this.function = function;
     }

     public T calculate() {
         return function.operate(Collections.unmodifiableMap(values));
     }

     // assume setters and getters are in place to manipulate the backing map and the functor object

}
```

With this in place, we can define various functions and calculations

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function<Integer> original = new Function<Integer>() {
        public Integer operate(Map<String,Integer> values) {
            // these will throw exceptions if they don't exist, which is desired
            // granted it's NullPointerException instead of IllegalStateException, but close enough for this example
            int age = values.get("age").intValue();
            int height = values.get("height").intValue();
            int fights = values.get("fights").intValue();
            return (age+height)*fights;
        }
    };
    Map<String,Integer> map = new Map<String,Integer>();
    map.put("age",10);
    map.put("height",100);
    map.put("fights",25);
    Calculation<Integer> calc = new Calculation<Integer>(map,original);

    // later someone can replace either the values in the backing map
    // or replace the function altogether to get a new function
}
```

The problem comes when you try to make it not only user defined, but user entered. As in, a user could define the function as being one of a set of functions you have pre-entered. In this case, you'll need to have a parser that turns something like this:

```
value + (other + (something * that)) / wazook
```

into this:

```
EquationBuilder<Integer> eb = new EquationBuilder<Integer>();
eb.append(map.get("value"));
eb.append(OPERATOR.PLUS);
// etc
return eb.evaluate();
```

But that may be beyond the scope of your assignment. Or maybe it's not.

Hopefully this is a little closer to your requirements than my previous example.

Comment: the problem glow coder is that the formula is user defined so it can be ANY number of size and any formula I was doing this part without a class…

Comment: @ashleysmith I revised my answer to meet my reevaluation of your requirements. How would this sort of approach work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at using one of a number of expression calculation engines instead of ArrayLists. You can see [Expr4J](http://expr4j.sourceforge.net/) or BIRT for possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to write an event listener for those arrays. Documentation can be found here
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listdatalistener.html

An easier solution is to write a simple method that computes the formula and call it from each portion of the program that triggers a change in the list values (but this solution can clutter the code). If this is a homework or really small project you can go with this approach otherwise I would suggest writing a listener.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'll use more OO manner, please take a look:

```
public class Parameter {
    private String id;
    private Number value;

    public Parameter(String id, Number value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Number getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Parameter) {
            Parameter parameter = (Parameter) obj;
            return id.equals(parameter.getId());
        }

        return super.equals(obj);
    }

}

public class Equation {
    private String formula;
    private Set<Parameter> parameters;

    public Equation(String formula, Parameter ... parameters) {
        this.formula = formula;
        this.parameters = new HashSet<Parameter>();
        for(Parameter parameter : parameters) {
            this.parameters.add(parameter);
        }
        validatePresenceOfAllParameters();
    }

    private void validatePresenceOfAllParameters() {
        // here you parse formula and check if all parameters are present
    }

    public Number doTheMagic() {
        Number result = null;
        // here you do the all magic related to equation and its parameters
        return result;
    }

    // public void setParameter(Parameter parameter)  {
    //  parameters.add(parameter);
    //  validatePresenceOfAllParameters();
    // }

}
```

I would also make `Parameter` and `Equation` object immutable, if there is a necessity of change I'll make another equation object but if this is the requirement you could write method in `Equation` for adding/setting `Parameter`'s. `Set` will handle them properly if they will have same id's.